# How to achieve a player that is not just a rectangle

Tags: lua, love2d

My goal is to achieve a player that is not just a rectangle.

This is my `love.load` and `love.draw`:

```
local AdvTiledLoader = require("AdvTiledLoader.Loader")
require("camera")

function love.load()
love.graphics.setBackgroundColor( 204, 255, 204 )
AdvTiledLoader.path = "maps/"
map = AdvTiledLoader.load("map.tmx")
map:setDrawRange(0, 0, map.width * map.tileWidth, map.height * map.tileHeight)

camera:setBounds(0, 0, map.width * map.tileWidth - love.graphics.getWidth(), map.height * map.tileHeight - love.graphics.getHeight() )

world =     {
            gravity = 1536,
            ground = 512,
            }

player =    {
            x = 256,
            y = 256,
            x_vel = 0,
            y_vel = 0,
            jump_vel = -1024,
            speed = 512,
            flySpeed = 700,
            state = "",
            h = 32,
            w = 32,
            standing = false,
            }
function player:jump()
    if self.standing then
        self.y_vel = self.jump_vel
        self.standing = false
    end
end

function player:right()
    self.x_vel = self.speed
end

function player:left()
    self.x_vel = -1 * (self.speed)
end

function player:stop()
    self.x_vel = 0
end

function player:collide(event)
    if event == "floor" then
        self.y_vel = 0
        self.standing = true
    end
    if event == "cieling" then
        self.y_vel = 0
    end
end

function player:update(dt)
    local halfX = self.w / 2
    local halfY = self.h / 2

    self.y_vel = self.y_vel + (world.gravity * dt)

    self.x_vel = math.clamp(self.x_vel, -self.speed, self.speed)
    self.y_vel = math.clamp(self.y_vel, -self.flySpeed, self.flySpeed)

    local nextY = self.y + (self.y_vel*dt)
    if self.y_vel < 0 then
        if not (self:isColliding(map, self.x - halfX, nextY - halfY))
            and not (self:isColliding(map, self.x + halfX - 1, nextY - halfY)) then
            self.y = nextY
            self.standing = false
        else
            self.y = nextY + map.tileHeight - ((nextY - halfY) % map.tileHeight)
            self:collide("cieling")
        end
    end
    if self.y_vel > 0 then
        if not (self:isColliding(map, self.x-halfX, nextY + halfY))
            and not(self:isColliding(map, self.x + halfX - 1, nextY + halfY)) then
                self.y = nextY
                self.standing = false
        else
            self.y = nextY - ((nextY + halfY) % map.tileHeight)
            self:collide("floor")
        end
    end

    local nextX = self.x + (self.x_vel * dt)
    if self.x_vel > 0 then
        if not(self:isColliding(map, nextX + halfX, self.y - halfY))
            and not(self:isColliding(map, nextX + halfX, self.y + halfY - 1)) then
            self.x = nextX
        else
            self.x = nextX - ((nextX + halfX) % map.tileWidth)
        end
    elseif self.x_vel < 0 then
        if not(self:isColliding(map, nextX - halfX, self.y - halfY))
            and not(self:isColliding(map, nextX - halfX, self.y + halfY - 1)) then
            self.x = nextX
        else
            self.x = nextX + map.tileWidth - ((nextX - halfX) % map.tileWidth)
        end
    end

    self.state = self:getState()
end

function player:isColliding(map, x, y)
    local layer = map.tl["Solid"]
    local tileX, tileY = math.floor(x / map.tileWidth), math.floor(y / map.tileHeight)
    local tile = layer.tileData(tileX, tileY)
    return not(tile == nil)
end

function player:getState()
    local tempState = ""
    if self.standing then
        if self.x_vel > 0 then
            tempState = "right"
        elseif self.x_vel < 0 then
            tempState = "left"
        else
            tampState = "stand"
        end
    end
    if self.y_vel > 0 then
        tempState = "fall"
    elseif self.y_vel < 0 then
        tempState = "jump"
    end
    return tempState
end
end

function love.draw()
camera:set()

love.graphics.setColor( 255, 161, 65 )
love.graphics.rectangle("fill", player.x - player.w/2, player.y - player.h/2, player.w, player.h)

love.graphics.setColor( 255, 255, 255 )
map:draw()

camera:unset()
end

function love.update(dt)
if dt > 0.05 then
    dt = 0.05
end
if love.keyboard.isDown("d") then
    player:right()
end
if love.keyboard.isDown("a") then
    player:left()
end
if love.keyboard.isDown(" ") and not(hasJumped) then
    player:jump()
end

player:update(dt)

camera:setPosition( player.x - (love.graphics.getWidth()/2), player.y - (love.graphics.getHeight()/2))
end

function love.keyreleased(key)
if (key == "a") or (key == "d") then
    player.x_vel = 0
end
end
```

Comment: Right of the bat you don't need `width` and `height` - love2d automatically draws images at their native resolution.  You're effectively squaring the widths and height of the image.  Also, what are `camera` and `map`?

Comment: @SelectricSimian its the map I use.
And the camera is the camera that follows the player :)

Comment: @SelectricSimian Do you want me to paste all my code? Its like 180 lines but I can do it :)

Comment: Nevermind what I said about width and height - I had the arguments reversed.  Sorry.  Can you be more specific about what your map and camera objects do?  It's possible they're the problem.

Comment: 2 sec ill just drop in the full code :)

Comment: The source of `camera:set()` and `camera:unset()` would be useful.

Comment: Also your map might be drawing over the player.  Try drawing the player after the map.

Comment: @SelectricSimian my comp just crashed I will post it now :D

Comment: @SelectricSimian Everything is ther now :D

Comment: @SelectricSimian In this one its working but only with a rectangle.

Can you maybe help me make the Rectangle a img I can draw?

Comment: It looks to me like `camera` is in another file though, which I think is a likely candidate for the location of the problem.  Could you please post that as well?  Also, what kind of error are you getting?  Is the game crashing, or just not drawing the player how you want?

Comment: @SelectricSimian in the code I have posted everything works, but the player is only a rectangle, I want to make him a img I can draw.

Comment: @SelectricSimian I have tried alot of things but I end up getting (a nil value) or a problem at: player:update(dt) : which is in the love.update.

Comment: @SelectricSimian You still here? :)

Comment: I'm eating dinner.  I'll be back in a few minutes.

Comment: @SelectricSimian I gtg in some min I guess ill come back later and hope you have found a answer :)

Comment: Please, don't repost almost the same question multiple times. Edit your question to improve it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to have your player appear as something other than a rectangle, you might want to have a look at the documentation for LOVE's [graphics module](http://www.love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics).

Right now, you're just calling `love.graphics.rectangle(...)` to draw the player, but you've got a lot of options:

For instance, if you wanted to have your player appear as the image `someimage.png` (which must be in the same directory as your game) you'd have to take two steps:

1. In your `love.load` handler, you should create the image object and store it somewhere.

   ```
   myimage = love.graphics.newImage("someimage.png")
   ```
2. In your `love.draw` handler, you should draw that image at the appropriate position.

   ```
   love.graphics.draw( myimage, player.x, player.y )
   ```

It's important that you load the image once (in `love.load`) and not every frame.

LOVE has a lot of flexbility when it comes to drawing, so I'd recommend you read up on all the different drawing tools you have in `love.graphics`.

Take a look at:

- [love.graphics.draw](http://www.love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.draw)
- [Image](http://www.love2d.org/wiki/Image)
- and anything else of interest in the `love.graphics` documentation. (linked above)

Comment: It works but the player img only fills up 1/4 of the square any idea how to fix this? @qu4ntumcpa

Comment: I'm assuming that your grid is 32x32px, so--just a sanity check--what size is your image? If you're not sure, open it in an image editor and check the size.